# Can we add stylesheet to window.open popup

Tags: javascript

I am creating a popup from javascript with window.open, My popup link is some 3rd party site link. I want to override some css classes for loading popup content.

Is it possible?

I tried with below code, but it is not working.

```
    e = window.open('external-url', 'test window', options)
    var head  = e.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = e.document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css url hosted on my site';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot edit an external site you have opened, that would be a huge security issue, see [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). You can however set the height, width, location on the screen, scrollbars visibility and some other properties for the opened window, see [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

You may implement in `<iframe>` tags. Check this example
http://jsfiddle.net/wxasfymL/3/